# Could it be because I'm using relative in the section I created, because it exceeds the limits of the html tag?

Tags: html, css, overflow, web-frontend

[overflow section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKcmU.png)

The section I created does not shrink after a certain point (probably 300-odd px). How can I prevent or solve this?

I tried the resize cards. But I wonder is there a more logical and technical solution?

Comment: Hello Natürealist, Welcome to SO, please read the [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) before posting so you can be familiar with the SO rules, and please include a [mre] to let others understand your problem and help you fix your problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.